# Geoip Span city not working second time

Tags: geoip, maxmind, city

this is seriously bugging me since last week. i am making a webpage and have to use  several times. but only thing is, when i use that code a second time, it will not display the CITY name output.

Here is the code i am using. what m i doing wrong?

In this code, when you run it, you will notice that it will only display your city 1 time, second code wont run for some reason. I hope i am clear in what i am asking. feel free to ask any questions.

This is scripts part:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://js.maxmind.com/js/apis/geoip2/v2.1/geoip2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script>
    var onSuccess = function(geoipResponse) {
        var cityElement = document.getElementById('city');
        if (cityElement) {
            cityElement.textContent = geoipResponse.city.names.en || 'Unknown city';
        }

        var countryElement = document.getElementById('country');
        if (countryElement) {
            countryElement.textContent = geoipResponse.country.names.en || 'Unknown country';
        }
    };

    var onError = function(error) {
        window.console.log("something went wrong: " + error.error)
    };

    var onLoad = function() {
        geoip2.city(onSuccess, onError);
    };

    // Run the lookup when the document is loaded and parsed. You could
    // also use something like $(document).ready(onLoad) if you use jQuery.
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', onLoad);
    </script>
```

This is body part:

```
<span id="country"></span> <span id="city"></span><span id="city"></span>
```

Comment: "it will only display your city 1 time, second code wont run for some reason" - how are you running it a second time, refreshing the page? Can you watch traffic in your browser debugging tools to see what request it is making for the second time? I assume you don't get a 'something went wrong' log, or a script error?

Comment: second time i mean is, the second code for CITY wont display city 2nd time. it should display city 2 times on the page.

Comment: Oh I see: you've got two elements id="city", and you want your code to populate them both. The problem is `document.getElementById('city');` is only going to return one of them. You can give them different IDs and populate them both e.g. by duplicating the city code or repeat the same code in a loop with both IDs, or you can use a different way to find both spans for the city e.g. by using a class and a getElementsBy- something call that will return them both.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the help, as you suggested, copying the

```
var cityElement = document.getElementById('city');
```

and renaming to city2 on the second code worked for me. this is a simple workaround but works for me.

Thanks :)